# how to increase resolution of linux virtual box guest

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I've got ubuntu installed on virtual box, on a windows7 host

The default resolution for ubuntu is 800 x 600, how can I increase this?

My windows7 resolution is high, this makes my virtual box window very small and difficult to use

On ubuntu, I can't seem to find a way to increase the resolution, I only have choice of 800 x 600

Do I need to install some drivers?

Comment: Did you install the Virtual Box Guest Additions? I'm pretty sure they're required to be able to adjust the resolution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be sure to have the guest additions installed, and to do that it is best to install the [dynamic kernel module support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) (dkms) package first. From a terminal / command prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Once that has been installed, you can mount the guest additions ISO and run the installer script, reboot and you should be able to adjust the resolution, run in seamless mode, etc:

```
sudo /media/VBOX*/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

There are some additional ideas and advice given on the Ubuntu StackExchange site:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Use xrandr in your guest, In your case "ubuntu" BUT PAY ATTETION  in a "BRAND NEW TERMINAL"

Example:

```
$  xrandr -q


Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 3200 x 900, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX0 connected 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
VBOX1 connected 1600x900+1600+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

As you can see I dont have 1920x1280 so I did:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1280" 60.0 1920 1600 1600 1440 1280 1024 800 640 -hsync +vsync
```

and now ...

```
xrandr --output VBOX1 --mode 1920x1280
```

and now ...

```
$ xrandr -q


Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 3520 x 1280, maximum 32000 x 32000
VBOX0 connected 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
VBOX1 connected 1920x1280+1600+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1280      60.0 +   65.1* 
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0
```

Make sure your "host" have resolution to your VBOX1.

Regards,