# vbox windows 8 guest on a Mac book retina resolution

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, macbook-pro-retina

I'm using a retina Mac book pro, and using virtual box.

How can I use the high resolution(2560*1600) in a windows 8.1 guest OS ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Be more clearly, I have already installed the guest addons, and set the video memory 128MB, but in the guest os(windows 8.1) the highest resolution is still 1440*900, in mac os I have 2560*1600 resolution on the retina screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In VirtualBox can't get max display resolution for guest OS](http://superuser.com/questions/289254/in-virtualbox-cant-get-max-display-resolution-for-guest-os), [how to increase resolution of linux virtual box guest](http://superuser.com/questions/172972/how-to-increase-resolution-of-linux-virtual-box-guest?rq=1), [Ubuntu resolution on Virtual Box(Mac OSX)](http://superuser.com/questions/135039/ubuntu-resolution-on-virtual-boxmac-osx?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

to accomplish this, you will need to install the guest addons.  Once you have installed these, the maximum resolution you can work with is higher than your stated screewn resolution (can't remember the exact numbers)

Also - if this doesn't fix it, you may need to allocate more memory to the virtual vidseo card assigned to your VM.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I have already installed the guest addons, and set the video memory is 128MB. My MBP retina's resulution is 2560*1600, but in the guest os(windows 8.1) highest resolution is still 1440*900